# Create a deployment from a pod in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

For a use case I need to create deployments from a pod when a script is being executed from inside the pod.

I am using google container engine for my cluster.

How to configure the container inside the pod to be able to run commands like kubectl create deployment.yaml?

P.S A bit clueless about it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your container is going to need to have `kubectl` available. There are some [container images available](https://www.google.com/search?q=kubectl%20docker%20image), personally I can't vouch for any of them.

Personally I'd probably build my own and download the latest `kubectl`. A Dockerfile like this is probably a good starting point

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add curl

RUN curl https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/$(curl -s https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

This will build you a container image with `kubectl`, so you can then all the `kubectl` commands you want.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. Used the one mentioned in kubernetes github repo. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/kubectl-container.